# SQL Keeps telling Syntax - Error at INNER JOIN, but gives no reason

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-delete

```
DELETE FROM mitarbeiter m
WHERE m.pers_nr IN  (SELECT COUNT(*) AS count 
                     FROM kunde 
                     GROUP BY betreuer)
INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS count 
            FROM kunde 
            GROUP BY betreuer ORDER BY count ASC LIMIT 1) AS x ON count = x.count
```

The compiler output is:

> ERROR: FEHLER:  Syntaxerror at »INNER«
> LINE 10:      INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM kunde GROUP B...

Does someone see the source of the error?

Comment: In standard SQL you can't use `INNER JOIN` in a `DELETE` statement. Additionally `pers_nr IN (select count(*) ...)` makes no sense whatsoever. Why would you match a "pers_nr" against a count of rows?

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL. Yes. I will add the tag! Okay i will think about it again.. i thought even without selecting pers_nr it would be able to find it

Comment: You've got an answer already, but I'll point this out:  you can't put a `WHERE` clause _before_ a `JOIN` clause in a SQL command. That may be why it said you had a syntax error as opposed to some other kind of error.  The `WHERE` clause has to come _after_ any `FROM` clause, and the `JOIN` is always part of a `FROM` clause.

Comment: Also, if the answer you posted the happy comment to helped you, be sure to mark it as your Accepted answer!

Answer (score 1):

You meant inner join belongs to subquery, right? Inner join is unnecessary there.

```
DELETE FROM mitarbeiter m
WHERE m.pers_nr IN  (SELECT COUNT(*) AS count 
                     FROM kunde 
                     GROUP BY betreuer
                     ORDER BY COUNT(*) LIMIT 1);
```

EDIT: This one deletes the employee having least number of customers (if betreuer in kunde meant their Id in that table):

```
DELETE FROM mitarbeiter m
WHERE m.pers_nr IN  
    (select betreuer 
         from kunde
         group by betreuer
         having count(*)=
         (
            SELECT count(*)
            FROM kunde 
            group by betreuer
            order by count(*) 
            limit 1
         )
      );
```

If you have 5 employees only and all have 3 customers (then all have the least number of customers), then you would be deleting all of your employees.

Even if you delete just 1, think this logic a lot. I am a new employee, who just joined the company and you would be deleting me if this runs at an early time after I was registered and not yet amde any customers (and you don't know if I had a seriously large customer portfolio I have brought in from the former company).

Comment: You are right! Thanks for the help guys! I think i thought too complicated :D
I think the employee isnt happy for deleting him because of having the lowest amount of customers :D

Comment: @Niklas, you are not deleting the employee with lowest number customers. You are deleting the employee, whose employee ID number is equal to the lowest number of customers in kinde grouped by betreuer. I will edit my reply to reflect what you said.

Comment: @Niklas, edited. Please do not skip the comments at the end.